# C, creating one way linked list from file

Tags: c, linked-list

Got it working. I'm just dumb and wrote `=` instead `==` in one place t.t Thanks all.

I have file with my data, and now i want to read it and put it into list. I don't fully know how to do it and since I have to finish this project in near future I simply ask you for help ;]

header file:

```
typedef struct
{
    char category[50];
    char name[50];
    char ingredients[50]; 
    char instruction[1000];
}recipe_t;



typedef struct element
{
    struct element *next;
    recipe_t recipe;

} el_list;

void all_recipe_list();
void show_all_list(el_list *list);
void add_new_element_to_list(el_list *list, recipe_t formula);
```

my list functions file:

```
void all_recipe_list() //reading all record into list + show it(show_all_list function)
{
FILE *database;
recipe_t formula;
el_list *head;

        head = NULL; 

    database = fopen(filename, "rb");
        fgetc(database);        // function feof returns value only if we read something before, so in order to check if its end, we try to read one char 
                                // when writing data to file, I put \n always before new record 
    while (!feof(database))
    {
        fread(&formula, sizeof(recipe_t),1,database);   

        if (head == NULL)
        {   
            head = malloc(sizeof(el_list));
            head->recipe = formula;
            head->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
        add_new_element_to_list(head,formula);
        }

        fgetc(database);    // same as above
    }
    fclose(database);


        show_all_list(head);

}


void show_all_list(el_list *list)
{
el_list *p=list;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("Kategoria:%s\n", p->recipe.category);
        printf("Nazwa:%s\n", p->recipe.name);
        printf("Skaldniki:%s\n", p->recipe.ingredients);
        printf("Instrukcja:%s\n", p->recipe.instruction);

        p = p->next;
    }
}

void add_new_element_to_list(el_list *list, recipe_t formula)
{
el_list *p, *new_el;

        p = list;
        while (p->next != NULL)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }

        new_el = malloc(sizeof(el_list));
        new_el->recipe = formula;
        new_el->next = NULL;
        p->next= new_el;
}
```

What are the problems?
Program is compiling allright but it's crashing when all_recipe_list is called.
It's probably something wrong with add_new_element_to_list. Can't figure out what though.
Also I don't know if in show_all_list p->recipe.category is right way to do it.

Comment: There's an error in `add_new_element_to_list` that jumps right out- what's the line `new_el->recipe;` doing? Also, you can probably just remove `p` altogether and use the `list` pointer.

Comment: I like this line `new_el->recipe;`.

Comment: Don't use `feof` like that - just check the return value of your `fread` call.

Comment: `new_el->recipe` corrected.
about `feof` I will change it later.

Comment: Just a side note, don't typedef things with identifiers that end with _t; these are reserved for future use.
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

Answer (score 0):

In `add_new_element_to_list()` this line:

```
new_el->recipe;
```

should read:

```
new_el->recipe = recipe;
```

I assume.

Comment: Yea it should be right that, I will change the second "recipe" to "formula" in a sec in my post. But it is still crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line `new_el->recipe;` to `new_el->recipe = recipe;` in the `add_new_element_to_list()` function.

Comment: If you're out of accessible memory it could be crashing on the `malloc`, you may want to add code after those lines along the lines of `if (head == NULL) exit(0);`. It could just be a problem with the reading of the files with what Carl said.

Comment: Rofl, got it working.... I had `if (head = NULL)` instead of `if (head == NULL)`. Ty ;]